# How to call method that takes interface as a parameter? Symfony - PHP

Tags: php, symfony

I feel so stupid, but I don't know how to call a function that takes interface as a parameter. So I added a method in my class:

```
public function sendSpool($messages = 10, KernelInterface $kernel)
{
    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = new ArrayInput(array(
       'command' => 'swiftmailer:spool:send',));

    $output = new BufferedOutput();
    $application->run($input, $output);

    $content = $output->fetch();

    return new Response($content);
}
```

How would I call it from my controller?

I tried:

```
$this->sendSpool('test', KernelInterface::class);
```

Then:

```
$kernel = new HttpKernel();
$this->sendSpool('test', $kernel );
```

This Kernel interface is in my use statement

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
```

, but I don't know how to pass it, please help explaining it to me if someone has couple of minutes. Thanks.

Comment: In which class do you define your `public function sendSpool`?

Comment: Depending on the Symfony version you use, in Symfony 3.3 and newer you don't need to provide the object yourself as it might get autowired. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#autowiring-logic-explained

Answer (score 5):

You need to use an instance of a class that implements the interface. Basically, it's asking to give you a class that has the functions available as described in the interface.

```
class MyKernel implements KernelInterface { /* functions here */ }
class x {
  function x() {
    $obj = new MyKernel();
    $this->sendSpool('test', $obj);
  }
}
```

In Symfony usually there is a way to get your kernel. Something like:

```
$this->getApplication()->getKernel()
```

But it depends on your use case.

Also, you need the use statement in the class that implements the interface, you don't need it on the place where you are using it.